# No method error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

please try to understand my question:

when i shut down the webrick server and again restart it ,then in my index view file there are some records after starting server if i click on any of three option (show,edit,delete)it gives me error "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass"  and for "show" option "undefined method`name' for nil:NilC"
but if i add new record then every thing works fine i dont know what is the error
this is delete file

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div>
  <h2>Delete vendor</h2>

  <%= form_for(:vendor, url: {action:'destroy', id: @vendor.id}) do |f| %>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this vendor?</p>

    <p><%= @vendor.name %></p>

    <div>
      <%= submit_tag("Delete vendor") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

and this is controller

```
class VendorController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @vendors=Vendor.all
  end

  def new
    #initiate new vendor which hits back to create
    @vendor=Vendor.new
  end

  def create
     @vendor=Vendor.new(vendor_params)
    if@vendor.save
      flash[:notice]="vendor ceated"
      redirect_to(action: 'index')
    else
      flash[:notice]="there is error"
      render('new')
  end

  def show
    @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id])
    if @vendor.update_attributes(vendor_params)
      flash[:notice]='record updated'
      redirect_to(action:'index')
    else
      flash[:notice]='there is some error'
      render('edit')
  end
end

  def delete
   @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id])      
  end

  def destroy
     @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id]).destroy
      if @vendor.destroy
      redirect_to(action: 'index')
    else
      render('delete')
  end
 end
end

private

def vendor_params
      params.require(:vendor).permit(:name ,:image_url)
end
end
```

this is edit

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}) %>

<div>
  <h2>update Vendor</h2>

      <%= form_for(:vendor, :url => {:action => 'update', id: @vendor.id }) do |f| %>

        <%= render(partial:"form" , locals: {f: f}) %>

        <div class="form-buttons">
          <%= submit_tag("Update vendor") %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

this is show

```
<%= link_to("<<BAck to main",{action:"index"}) %>
<div>
<h1>showing <%=@vendor.name %></h1>
<p><%=@vendor.image_url %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't do this `@vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id]).destroy`. Instead do `@vendor=Vendor.find(params[:id])` then `if @vendor.destroy`

Comment: ok but show and edit are also not working but if i add record in database then every things works fine include delete option

Comment: Can you update your question with **Show** and **Edit** erbs

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Seems your `@vendor` is nil. Check your server params if it's passing **id**

Comment: some one suggest me that my naming of controller and db is not good so that i am facing this error ...so i am working on it ....and for your question answer is yes its passing id

Comment: Try `Rails.logger.info @vendow.inspect` in **show** or **edit** method to see if `@vendor` is nil

Comment: thanks for your help problem is solve. my controller name was singular that was the problem now i change it to plural and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Good to see you fixed the problem.

--

For the benefit of future visitors, the error was caused by your controller name being singular, rather than plural.

All controllers should be named in the *plural*; all models in the *singular*:

```
#app/models/vendor.rb
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
end
```

---

As an added recommendation, your forms could be tidied up considerably by using the `@vendor` variable:

```
#app/views/vendors/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @vendor do |f| %>
```

This will auto-fill the path and method, depending on the construct of the object you've passed.